# Working With A PHP Exploded String

Tags: php

### PHP Script:

```
$path = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
$parts = explode('/', $path);
$count = count($parts);
echo "<script>console.log('URL Path: $path');</script>";
echo "<script>console.log('Parts Length: $count');</script>";
foreach($parts as $i =>$key) {
    $i >0;
    echo "<script>console.log('Part $i). $key');</script>";
}
echo "<script>console.log('Test: $key[3]');</script>";
```

### Outcome:

Tested URL: domain.com/Projects/A/B/C

> URL Path: Projects/A/B/C
>
> Parts Length: 4
>
> Part 0). Projects
>
> Part 1). A
>
> Part 2). B
>
> Part 3). C
>
> Test:

### Question:

As you can see from my outcome, my `echo "<script>console.log('Test: $key[3]');</script>";` attempt to log a specific part does not work. How can I get `part[X]` from my exploded string?

Comment: Put it in the loop. `$key` is not an array though so not exactly clear what you are doing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your value in parts (and not in $key outside the foreach)

```
    $path = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    $parts = explode('/', $path);
    $count = count($parts);
    echo "<script>console.log('URL Path: $path');</script>";
    echo "<script>console.log('Parts Length: $count');</script>";
    foreach($parts as $i =>$key) {
        $i >0;
        echo "<script>console.log('Part $i). $key');</script>";
    }

    echo "<script>console.log('Test: " . $parts[3] . " ');</script>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @scaisEdge.